# How does Feedly determine Twitter name?

Tags: security, twitter, feedly

When trying out http://www.feedly.com/ I noticed it automatically recognized my Twitter-name. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it runs as a browser addin, I'd assume that it makes a web request to twitter using your existing login cookie (which wouldn't be allowed for a website due to security restrictions) and gets your twitter username as part of the response.

Answer (score 2):

As a Firefox add-on, it has access to your cookies, and thus, when you're logged in to twitter, to your twitter account name.